# How do I convert this iterative function to a recursive one?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, hashmap, iteration

This function map input strings to that in a dictionary, outputting the result. Any idea how this can be approached recursively?

```
def dna(seq):
    hashtable = {'A': 'U', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A', 'C': 'G'}
    ans = ''
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        ans += hashtable[seq[i]]
    return ans


print(dna('AGCTGACGTA'))
```

Thanks.

Comment: In theory, any iteration can be rewritten into recursion. In practice, Python is not very good at it, and in this case the iterative approach is preferable; there is nothing to be gained from recursion. This code could be improved (`for ch in seq`, or using comprehensions, or best of all using `str.translate`), but what you currently have is still much better than recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should understand recursion is not always the answer.

There is a maximum recursion depth in python which you can change. But still you will have a limit. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323013/2681662

The maximum recursion depth allowed:

```
import sys
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
```

So iterative approach is better in your case.

Still let's see how the recursive version would look like.

For a recursive function you have to follow simple rules:

1. Create an exit condition
2. Call yourself (the function) again.

```
def dna_r(seq):
    hashy = {'A': 'U', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A', 'C': 'G'}
    if len(seq) == 1:
        return hashy[seq]

    return dna_r(seq[0]) + dna_r(seq[1:])
```

Comment: Apologies in advance but being someone that is rlly new to recursion, may I ask why the loop doesnt just end in the first loop when dna_r(first letter) is called as it satisfies the base case?

Comment: Actually it ends when the function calls `dna_r(first letter)` for the first letter. But we call the function again for remaining letters using `dna_r(seq[1:])`.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```py
def dna(seq):
    if not seq:
        return ''
    return {'A': 'U', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A', 'C': 'G'}[seq[0]] + dna(seq[1:])
```

Although this is almost certainly slower, uses more memory, and will hit Python's recursion limit. The recommended approach for almost all usecases would be iterative; modify your code to use Python's builtin string join:

```py
def dna(seq):
    hashtable = {'A': 'U', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A', 'C': 'G'}
    ans = []
    for elem in seq:
        ans.append(hashtable[elem])
    return ''.join(ans)
```